# Differentiation of $f(f(x,y),f(x,f(x,y)))$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $f(x,y)$ be a continuously differentiable function of two variables. How do I calculate the derivative with respect to $x$ of $f(f(x,y),f(x,f(x,y)))$. Thanks.

Comment: Using the chain rule, what else? :P (<- not helpful comment.)  Seriously, though, you do need to use the chain rule.  It's a bit too much of a mess for me to draw right now, but a good start would be to draw a tree diagram of the functions...

Comment: Does you mean the first partial w.r.t. $x$? Are $x$ and $y$ both independent, or are you intending that $y$ is a function of $x$?

Answer (score 0):

You do it recursively. Swtiching between notation can help keep placemarkers for the undone parts:
$$
   \frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(f(x,y),f(x,f(x,y))) =f_{x}(f(x,y),f(x,f(x,y)))\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y)+f_{y}(f(x,y),f(x,f(x,y)))\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,f(x,y))
$$
$$
   = f_{x}(f(x,y)f(x,f(x,y)))f_{x}(x,y)+f_{y}(f(x,y),f(x,f(x,y)))\left\{ f_{x}(x,f(x,y))+f_{y}(x,f(x,y))\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y)\right\}
$$
$$
   = f_{x}(f(x,y)f(x,f(x,y)))f_{x}(x,y)+f_{y}(f(x,y),f(x,f(x,y)))\{\; f_{x}(x,f(x,y))+f_{y}(x,f(x,y))f_{x}(x,y)\;\}
$$